# How implement CArrayDataProvider in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, yii, cgridview

I'm new to Yii. I'm using CArrayDataProvider to pass data in my CGridView but I'm getting an error of undefined id. Can you help me to check if I missed something?

index.php (View)

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider' => $arrayDataProvider,
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'LastName',
        'type' => 'raw',
                        'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["LastName"])'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'FirstName',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data["FirstName"])',
    ),
),
));
```

RecordsController.php

```
public function actionIndex()
{  

        $data = new TblAccountdetails();
        $rawData = $data->getAllData();
        $arrayDataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
                'id'=>'id',
                'pagination'=>array(
                        'pageSize'=>10,
                ),
        ));

        $params =array(
                'arrayDataProvider'=>$arrayDataProvider,
        );

        if(!isset($_GET['ajax'])) $this->render('index', $params);
        else  $this->renderPartial('index', $params);
}
```

My Model Function

```
public function getAllData()
    {
         $user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('AID, LastName, FirstName')
            ->from('tbl_accountdetails')
            ->queryAll();
        return $user;
    }
```

Vardump of $arrayDataProvider

```
  object(CArrayDataProvider)#32 (11) {
  ["keyField"]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["rawData"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["AID"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["LastName"]=>
      string(8) "Floresca"
      ["FirstName"]=>
      string(5) "Joene"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["AID"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["LastName"]=>
      string(13) "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      ["FirstName"]=>
      string(12) "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["AID"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["LastName"]=>
      string(7) "Antonio"
      ["FirstName"]=>
      string(4) "Noel"
    }
  }
  ["caseSensitiveSort"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_id":"CDataProvider":private]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["_data":"CDataProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_keys":"CDataProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_totalItemCount":"CDataProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_sort":"CDataProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_pagination":"CDataProvider":private]=>
  object(CPagination)#33 (9) {
    ["pageVar"]=>
    string(7) "id_page"
    ["route"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["params"]=>
    NULL
    ["validateCurrentPage"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["_pageSize":"CPagination":private]=>
    int(10)
    ["_itemCount":"CPagination":private]=>
    int(0)
    ["_currentPage":"CPagination":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_e":"CComponent":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_m":"CComponent":private]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["_e":"CComponent":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_m":"CComponent":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

I don't know where I get that undefined id error:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.one way is to change

`->select('AID, LastName, FirstName')`

into

`->select('AID as id, LastName, FirstName')`

2.you can also set `keyField` this way

```
$arrayDataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
            'id'=>'nameThisProvider',
            'keyField' => 'AID'
            'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>10,
            ),
));
```

3.you could use a [CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider)